# Want to validate the check box in magento using magento validation

Tags: php, validation, magento

I want to set the required field for the check box
i tried my coding

```
 <input class="checkbox required-entry" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
<input class="checkbox required-entry" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
<input class="checkbox required-entry" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
<input class="checkbox required-entry" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
<input class="checkbox required-entry" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
```

i check any one of the field and  press submit button the remaining field shows "This is a required field" .
I Want to set the required field in check box if i not check any one of the value the required message will show other wise if not mandatory

Thank You

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Really Easy Field validation](http://ranawd.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/really-easy-field-validation-with-prototype/):

> - validate-one-required (At least one textbox/radio element must be selected in a group – see below*)
>
> *To use the validate-one-required validator you must first add the class name to only one checkbox/radio button in the group (last one is probably best) and then place all the input elements within a parent element, for example a div element. That way the library can find all the checkboxes/radio buttons to check and place the validation advice element at the bottom of the parent element to make it appear after the group of checkboxes/radio buttons.

Therefore you could do this:

```
<fieldset>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox validate-one-required" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
</fieldset>
```

But since those checkboxes share the same name (this isn't documented but is in the source) you could also do:

```
<!-- Maybe these are columns and don't share a parent element -->
<div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox validate-one-required-by-name" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <!-- This checkbox is lowest on the page so should have the message -->
</div>
<div>
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Its Works .You save lot of time for me..:)

Comment: Your code is fine but i need to show a error message also. is that possible.

Answer (score 3):

add `required-entry` to its class

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id" name="name" value="value" class="checkbox required-entry">
```

Comment: I tried but if i set required for each and every field if take mandatory field for all field.when i press submit button if shows all fiels is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You can use : **validate-one-required-by-name** as long the inputs share the same name (which is usually the case)